# Summarizing sets of calculations using cells on different rows

Tags: vba, function, excel, loops

I have a list of accounts and transactions with four columns in each row. "Transaction#". "Paid". "Owing". "Notes".

I get updates for each client each day with an unknown number of rows and I want to build a VBA function which will help check and summarize each sheet. Here's what I'm trying to make it do for a sheet with 4 rows.

A                 B          C            D                     E 
1001       100       150       notes       (my calculation)
1002       150       250       notes       (my calculation)
1003       250       400       notes       (my calculation)
1004       400       500       notes       (my calculation)

My calculation in each case is to copy and paste a formula manually to check that:
C1 is the same as B2,
C2 is the same as B3, etc.

But I find that this is slow and errors in copying can cause me huge headaches as I have to find the problems manually.

So, I am making a VBA script to start on Row 2 and check that the B value of each row is the same as the C value of the previous row and return a Zero if there is no difference. (We start on row 2 so it has a previous value to compare to!). When I get to a blank line, I then have to stop so the last value is not nonsense, (it won't have a "B" value to compare with).

In case where a calculation does not match, I have to record the value so that I can go back and check the notes. I guess it would have to complete the check, no mater whether there are numerous mismatches or not... but give me a list of the bad rows to check

So my output msgbox would look something like:

"No matching errors"

or maybe a list:

"problems with Column B in transactions 1001, 1003, 1008, 100x..."

I hope this makes sense.

I will probably plan to make a button on the toolbar so I can load an xlsx file and then run the function right away to see how much checking i need to do!

I figured out how to look at each cell in a single column, stopping at a blank row, but that is as far as I got.

Comment: Conditional formatting seems like a simpler approach here, have you tried this yet?  You could simply use a formula to turn any cells that don't match red (or whatever you would like).

Comment: Thanks for the reply... Yes - it would work but sometimes i have 4000 lines PER CLIENT... so the looking through them for errors is still really, really time-comsuming. Thanks for the thought tho! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally I would go with this approach: use a simple if statement in column F that looks something like this:

```
=IF(C1=B2,"","Error")
```

You can then sort by "Error" in column F using the "Filter" under the "Data" ribbon to find all errors quickly, you could even have another formula in cell G1 like this:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(<Range of your error column>,"Error"), "Errors Present","No Errors")
```

You could even then condionally format that formula cell to be red if it is "Errors Present"

Depending on the amount of data, you will probably want to create dynamic ranges for column F so you can copy and paste the forumla down the column, then copy the whole range are re-paste as values since excel re-calculates every formula every time it calculates a formula and this will get quite time consuming.

You could even build yourself an index page that will contain a forumal that checks all the "Error Present"/"No Errors" cell and tell you if any of your reports have errors to simplify things.  To be clear, there IS a way to do this with vba, but looping through large ranges becomes very inefficeint way of doing this, and as a new user I think this will do everything you need quickly, cleanly and efficiently.

Comment: Thanks! That works very well - i had to tinker until i understood exactly what you meant, but thank you for the pointers!